# HSQL Java Language Routines cause "General Error" (S1000) when called

Tags: java, sql, function, hsqldb

I am trying to migrate an old application from HSQLDB 1.8.0.10 to the latest version 2.5.1.

Everything has been going fine, but the old application added two `ALIAS`s for static Java methods:

```
statement.execute("CREATE ALIAS BigBitAnd FOR \"org.somedomain.ClassName.bigBitAnd\"");
statement.execute("CREATE ALIAS BigMod FOR \"org.somedomain.ClassName.bigMod\"");
```

with

```
public static long bigBitAnd(long a, long b) {
    return a & b;
}

public static long bigMod(long a, long b) {
    return a % b;
}
```

I have tried translating this to function definitions as follows:

```
statement.execute("CREATE FUNCTION BIGBITAND(a BIGINT, b BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:org.somedomain.ClassName.bigBitAnd'");
statement.execute("CREATE FUNCTION BIGBITAND(a BIGINT, b BIGINT) RETURNS BIGINT LANGUAGE JAVA DETERMINISTIC NO SQL EXTERNAL NAME 'CLASSPATH:org.somedomain.ClassName.bigMod'");
```

The functions are created successfully, but when they are applied in any statement via `PreparedStatement.executeQuery()`, the query fails with a "General Error" (S1000). A google search tells me this may be happening because of a NumberFormatException somewhere.

For testing purposes, I also tried hsqldb 2.3.6. It also failed with a "General Error" due to a NullPointerException.

Is there something wrong with my function declarations or are functions called differently than hsql 1.8 aliases?

Update: I tried replacing all occurrences of `BIGBITAND` with `BIGAND` calls, and the error no longer occurs. However, this leads to other issues because `BIGAND` does not apply to `BIGINT`, as far as I can tell.
It appears that the `BIGMOD` custom function does not lead to a General Error.

Update 2: With HSQLDB version 2.4.0, I get a more detailed stack trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hsqldb.RoutineSchema.getSpecificRoutine(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.FunctionSQLInvoked.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionLogical.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionLogical.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionLogical.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ExpressionLogical.resolveTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveExpressionTypes(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.resolveTypesPartOne(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.QueryExpression.resolve(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Update: I have created unit tests and executing both functions via CALL is successful.
I will write some more tests to see if they can be executed in query statements.

Comment: I think I may have found the cause:

It may be within the following statement snippet: `BIGBITAND(CASEWHEN(BIGMOD(p.val,2)=0,p.val+1,p.val-1),?) != 0`

It appears that hsql is trying to resolve `?` as a `BIGINT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the type of CASEWHEN expressions is not determined correctly or the type is not exactly right. You can always cast the function arguments, including the variable placeholder `?`, into the type you need. For example:

```
BIGBITAND(CAST( CASEWHEN(BIGMOD(p.val,2)=0,p.val+1,p.val-1) AS BIGINT), CAST(? AS BIGINT) ) != 0
```

P.S. The non-specific "General Error" is caused when the engine reports the actual error, which is this: `"routine signature not found for: PUBLIC.BIGBITAND(DECIMAL,null) in statement .."`. The data type of the expression `p.val+1` is DECIMAL due to automatic type widening. This causes the engine to look for a routine signature that does not exist.

Comment: Thanks. It works!
And casting is definitely an easier (and less error-prone) solution than formatting the statement manually.

I solved the automatic type widening issue with polymorphism. That wasn't really an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

When preparing a statement that has a `?` placeholder as a function argument, the HSQLDB connector attempts to resolve the type of the `?` placeholder, which fails.

A workaround is to replace the `?` placeholder manually, before preparing the statement. Not very clean, but at least it works.